# Excel VBA: how can I change the value in ComboBox before populating PDF (view detail)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build an automation tool to read inputs from a master data file with numerous cases, and for each case, do the necessary calculations and produce a report.

But, there are a few ComboBox in the input fields.

The calculation is based on the value in the ComboBox, and a report is created based on the output of the calc. It appears that the value in the ComboBox is updated now and so the calculation is actually correct using the correct input. BUT, when the PDF report is populated, it shows the initial value in the ComboBox, not the desired correct new input. And I see the ComboBox value is changed to the correct input AFTER the PDF is populated. This creates a problem as I have the correct outputs but misleading inputs in my reports. Is there any way I can have the value in the ComboBox changed BEFORE the PDF is populated?

```
Sheet7.ComboBox1.Value = "No"
```

Comment: The VBA trigger would most likely need to be a Change Event.  The combo box itself could be made wiht a data-validation list (using a named range or actual range reference), and the change event triggers as such.

Comment: Are you referring to a dataValidation dropdown? or what kind of ComboBox are you using?

Comment: Here is how to set data-validation ranges with vba: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357337/update-data-validation-list-range

Comment: Try wsTarget.ComboBox1.Value = "No" and so on. You will probably be better off by looping through all the comboboxes in the sheet and setting their values with this method. `For each ctrl in wsTarger.OLEObjects` and `ctrl.Name` might do the trick.

Comment: @Davesexcel I believe it is an ActiveX Control ComboBox

Comment: @MikaelKajander wsTarget.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value did not create any error but did not change the value of the ComboBox either. Any other idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for me.....

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    sh.ComboBox1.Value = "Run"

End Sub
```

But this does work for me...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value = "Run"

End Sub
```

Comment: The calculation is based on the value in the ComboBox, and a report is created based on the output of the calc. It appears that the value in the ComboBox is updated now and so the calculation is actually correct using the correct input. BUT, when the PDF report is populated, it shows the initial value in the ComboBox, not the desired correct new input. And I see the ComboBox value is changed to the correct input AFTER the PDF is populated. This creates a problem as I have the correct outputs but misleading inputs in my reports. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Could you edit your question with these added details